# preparing for first reset: how many kittens?

Tags: kittens-game

I've got Concrete Huts and 90 kittens so far, however I don't have Apocrypha yet and am trying to figure out when to push the reset button.

Progress so far:

- 145K science (haven't unlocked Biochemistry yet)
- 134K faith pool, 6400 max faith
- 4.47 craft multiplier (1 factory + 57 workshop)

Questions that come to mind:

- How many kittens -- I'm thinking I should run until it takes X amount of time to get another housing building. What should X be? 10 minutes? 1 hour?
- Should I sell any buildings to help speedup getting more kittens?
- Should I unlock Transcendence before reset?
- How many usages of Apocrypha?
- Anything else worth getting before reset?

I've read the reddit thread about [which items carry over at reset](https://www.reddit.com/r/kittensgame/comments/31c8p0/reset_mechanics/cq08ov1) but I'm still not sure when is best.

3 hours later after posting above, I am at 103 kittens, 151 science, 147K faith pool 7525 max faith (enough for Transcendence once I get enough accumulated faith), 4.79 craft multiplier (5 factory + 59 workshop). mansions are still relatively cheap: mansion #17 is 1731 slab 701 steel 234 titanium.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Around 50 paragon for your first run ought to be good, from a reset at 120 kittens, but it's more a matter of opinion and how long you can stand to push the first run without the bonus.

The general idea in most strategies around the first few resets is to make the most out of the paragon production bonus, and reduce the long run time on future runs.  The bonus is a flat 1% per point up through the first 150 points (after that the diminishing returns kick in).  As of your first post you would get 20 paragon and the later edit 33.  Staying in the run until you can get a full 50% boost will make the game feel much faster, and as a consequence make getting even more paragon (like the next 100 points) much easier.

Anything else you can work in is a bonus.  Getting Apocrypha for the religion reset bonus is a great thing - you don't need to use it at all except right before the reset, or the reset itself will do it for you, with just a smidge of value shaved off.  Some people find selling off helpful; I find it too much work.  Most everything else that carries over can wait until you have the paragon stocked up and speeding you up.

Comment: what about Transcendence?

Comment: I'm just gonna do Transcendence, I have enough faith and gold anyway.

Comment: @JasonS - it lets you upgrade most faith skills, but Apocrypha isn't one.  If you bought it and then bought lots of Solar Chant, you could rake in more faith to bank and feed to Apocrypha for reset bonus, but otherwise you can just bank what you have.

Comment: I went with 132 kittens (mansions slowing down), got 63 paragon (62 + 1 for reaching Y1000)

Comment: yay, 2nd time through I'm at about the same point in Y480.